# Extract vertex coordinates of a polygon on a map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, extract, vertices

How can I extract the vertex coordinates of a polygon on a map into CSV using QGIS?

Comment: The polygon is a vector layer?

Answer (score 8):

1. "Extract vertices" processing tool
2. Optional: "Remove duplicate vertices" processing tool
3. Save layer as csv:

   a) Right click layer -> Export -> Save Features As...

   b) Format -> Comma Separated Value [CSV]

   c) Optional: CRS -> "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84"

   d) Layer Options -> GEOMETRY -> AS_XY

   e) OK